# Ubuntu (14.04) sudden logout

Tags: 14.04, xorg, compiz, logout

My Ubuntu is suddenly logging me out. I don't know what I can make. Someone has some tips on how to debug this behavior? Which files do I need to check?

Here is the output from this command:

```
$ cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log.old| grep EE -B 5 -A 5
[ 22582.142] (II) Loading sub module "present"
[ 22582.142] (II) LoadModule: "present"
[ 22582.142] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module present
[ 22582.142] (II) UnloadModule: "present"
[ 22582.142] (II) Unloading present
[ 22582.142] (EE) intel: Failed to load module "present" (module does not exist, 0)
[ 22582.142] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[ 22582.142] (II) Unloading modesetting
[ 22582.142] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[ 22582.142] (II) Unloading fbdev
[ 22582.142] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
--
[ 23655.752] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[ 23655.753] (II) evdev: Video Bus: Close
[ 23655.753] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[ 23655.753] (II) evdev: Power Button: Close
[ 23655.753] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[ 23656.478] (EE) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

And this:

```
$ dmesg| tail                                                                                                          
[13567.228768] usbcore: registered new interface driver wacom
[13567.228807] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[13567.228810] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[13836.584251] compiz[9120]: segfault at 48 ip 00007f4c6563e840 sp 00007fffc863dbc8 error 4 in libscale.so[7f4c6562d000+27000]
[15528.486221] systemd-hostnamed[22530]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
[15841.471844] perf samples too long (5036 > 5000), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 25000
[19499.929076] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[22240.250334] compiz[20690]: segfault at 48 ip 00007f721cd5b840 sp 00007fff7e524c28 error 4 in libscale.so[7f721cd4a000+27000]
[22600.030214] compiz[26873]: segfault at 48 ip 00007f3bc2bf2840 sp 00007ffd5fb39548 error 4 in libscale.so[7f3bc2be1000+27000]
[23675.347947] compiz[28719]: segfault at 48 ip 00007f433b912840 sp 00007ffd581733a8 error 4 in libscale.so[7f433b901000+27000]
```

Comment: technically, i'm pretty sure it's not 'logging you out.' a program called compiz is crashing in a library called libscale, and killing your X server. then ubuntu is automatically restarting your X server, which presents you with the login screen like when it starts up normally. this may help you google for answers. also, you should paste the entire X logfile to pastebin or something like that.

Comment: @user3113723, thanks for the explanation.  In the dmesg above, I see the line **[15528.486221]** which says **Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed**. I installed it and the problem do not happen again.  Maybe this fixed the problem because I am always using ssh sessions and the problem used to happen when I were in an active connection.

Comment: @leoheck I think you can make your comment into an answer for this question. I also faced the same problem and your comment resolved it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem myself when I found a line in `dmesg` which says

```
Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed
```

I installed `nss-myhostname` and it fixed my problem. Maybe this fixed the problem because I am always using ssh sessions and the problem used to happen when I was in an active connection.